# wrong data after casting binary data to stucture

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I try to cast binary data to structure :

```
struct stats {
    unsigned char stats_id;
    unsigned short stats_length;
    unsigned char stats_records;
};

stats *p = (stats*)data; //data - char pointer to char buffer with binary data
```

but i get wrong result :
[image]

because i need this :
[image]

and i can get it if i do it like this :

```
unsigned char stats_id = *(data);
unsigned short stats_length = *(data+1);
unsigned char stats_records = *(data+3);
```

I have many same data and i think that casting to structure is the better way, so i don't want to use variant above(or i can make exeption but anyway i want to know solution of this problem). Other casting to structures works good, so just wrong with this scructure. At first time i thought that the  reason is in the aligment of this structure but tests with pragma give same results.

Comment: Seems like an alignment/padding issue, more specifically the alignment of `stats_length`. You say you tried `#pragma pack(1)` (or the equivalent for your compiler)?

Comment: It is a struct packing issue. Go read this guide: http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/ It will help you understand what you're seeing.

Comment: @Borgleader, hm now i am trying to use #pragma pack(1) and it's work but before i tried surround struct with `#pragma pack(push, 1)` and #pragma pack(pop) on my Visual C++ 2010 and this doesn't. How to return to previous state after using `#pragma pack(1)`? What i must use instead #pragma pack(pop) or it's ok?